# How can i make my iPhone Application to iPad Compatible without using Jailbreak?

Tags: iphone, ipad

i have made iPhone Application and i want to make it iPad Compatible without using Jailbreak mainly i have used ImageView,UITableView,UIScrollView that's it.

Comment: By default all iPhone apps can run on the iPad. So is there something special you are thinking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on your target and choose Upgrade Current Target for iPad.

[upgrade http://cl.ly/a6841500e61b3cd0e9a8/content](http://cl.ly/a6841500e61b3cd0e9a8/content)

Comment: YES,is there any thing to do after performing this step? Please let me know about it in some detail. Thanks for this help.

Comment: Follow the prompts, and then test to make sure it works. You can choose to test in the the iPad Simulator as well as iPhone Simulator. Follow the guide at http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/StartingYourProject/StartingYourProject.html

Answer (score 3):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad

As per your requirement i think it's a best example described here......